# Asterisk (AMI) get meetme user dialed exten value

Tags: asterisk

Is it possible, from a meetme user (ie `meetme list <roomno>`) to get the phone number that this user dialed? If we have set up a dial plan for more than one phone number, all leading to the same conference room (for allowing local calls to be made in the same conf. room), we need to get the phone number the user dialed (because there are `1-800` phone numbers, and we need to know which user use them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do following:

1) do

`meetme list concise roomno`

2) get channel name  and after that do

```
 core show channel channel_name
```

as rusult u will see all cahnnel's variables, including extension.

Comment: ncie! I couldn't ask for more info